# Angular 6 way of detecting changes inside an array of objects?

Tags: angular

I have a save button that needs to be disabled if no changes have been detected. I implemented my own change detection but I feel like something has to exist for Angular 6? I tried to use the DefaultKeyValueDiffer and IterableDiffer but could not figure out how to properly use them. Is it the right approach to use either one of these? Posted below is my current custom solution:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TagService } from '../../services/tag.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

import { Tag } from '../../models/tag';
import { Company } from '../../models/company';
import { TagColumnDetail } from '../../models/tag-column-detail';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  initialTagState: Tag[];
  tags: Tag[];
  updatedTags: Tag[];

  constructor(
    private tagService: TagService
   ) {}

  @ViewChild(TableComponent) table:TableComponent;

  ngOnInit() {  this.authService.getActiveCompany$().subscribe((company: Company) => {
      this.activeCompany = company;
      if (this.activeCompany) {
        Promise.all([
          this.tagService.getColumns(),
          this.tagService.getTags(this.activeCompany.Id)
        ]).then(([tagCols, tags]) => {
          this.tagCols = tagCols;
          this.setTags(tags, true);
          this.initialTagState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.tags));
        });
      }
    });
  }

  setTags(tags, init=false) {
    this.tags = tags
    if(!init) {
      this.changesMadeToPolicy()
    }
  }

  changesMadeToPolicy() {
    let changes = this._getChanges(this.initialTagState, this.tags)
    this.updatedTags = changes
  }

  _getChanges(oldArray, newArray) {
    let changes, i, item, j, len;
    if (JSON.stringify(oldArray) === JSON.stringify(newArray)) {
      return false;
    }
    changes = [];
    for (i = j = 0, len = newArray.length; j < len; i = ++j) {
      item = newArray[i];
      if (JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(oldArray[i])) {
        changes.push(item);
      }
    }
    return changes;
  };

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by implementing your own change detection? And why do you want to if ZoneJS does it for you?

Comment: I have an array of objects that I can manipulate in the UI by toggling. For example, I can toggle one object from on to off. If one of the objects in this array is updated/changed from on to off, that is considered a change. If I update the object from on to off and back to on then this is not a change and a change should not be detected since it was reset back to it's original starting state.

Comment: @Lucho can you provide an example of how I would use ZoneJs to do this?